# Is it possible to declare a constructor inside a method

Tags: java

I am looking for a ans what I have found in facebook and became confused 
"is it possible to declare a constructor inside a method"

Comment: constructors are declared inside a class..and not method.

Comment: I'm curious to know what you can possibly have read that would even give rise to this question.

Comment: If I play with your words, it __IS__ possible, if I declare a local class with its constructor inside a method, I would be declaring that constructor inside that method

Comment: '    public class testing 
    {
     public void fly(final int speed) 
        {
      final int e = 1;
      class Flying 
         {
          Flying()
          {
           System.out.println(e);// line 1
           System.out.println(speed);// line 2
       }
         }
         new Flying();
         return;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
         final int x = 5;
         testing test = new testing();
         test.fly(x);
        }
    }    '

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  **no**.

Long answer:  This comes from the [Java Language Specification, §8.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8):

> A constructor is used in the creation of an object that is an instance of a class.
>
> In all other respects, the constructor declaration looks just like a method declaration that has no result (§8.4.5).
>
> Constructor declarations are not members. They are never inherited and therefore are not subject to hiding or overriding.

It's declared like this:

```
ConstructorDeclaration:
    ConstructorModifiers(opt) ConstructorDeclarator
                            Throws(opt) ConstructorBody

ConstructorDeclarator:
    TypeParameters(opt) SimpleTypeName ( FormalParameterList(opt) )
```

A `ConstructorDeclarator` can only live inside of the [class body declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6):

```
ClassBody:
    { ClassBodyDeclarations(opt) }

ClassBodyDeclarations:
    ClassBodyDeclaration
    ClassBodyDeclarations ClassBodyDeclaration

ClassBodyDeclaration:
    ClassMemberDeclaration
    InstanceInitializer
    StaticInitializer
    ConstructorDeclaration <--

ClassMemberDeclaration:
    FieldDeclaration
    MethodDeclaration
    ClassDeclaration    
    InterfaceDeclaration
    ;
```

A [`MethodDeclaration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) has no symbol to a `ConstructorDeclaration`, which is why you cannot declare a constructor inside of a method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a constructor inside a method.

Constructors and methods are both components of objects. Your object has a constructor that gets called when you instantiate it. Once instantiated, your object then has properties to define it, and methods to do things with.

If you try to place a constructor into a declaration, you will get a compilation error.

This comes from several years of practice and study for the Sun certification tests.

Comment: *"This comes from several years of practice and study for the Sun certification tests."* - Surely they are not *that* hard ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.java does not support inner methods concept.Constructor is also like a method.Constructors can be declared inside a class only.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor *is* sort of a method much like the main method. The constructor is used to initialize an object of the class and it has no return value.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all possible.

A constructor  must invoked while creating object for a `class`.

With out instance how you will call that method,which is building the `constructor`?.

Making any sense ?

Comment: The method could be static, or inside another class.

Comment: static method is ok,but inside that method  OP wants to create constructor ,will it possible ?